# HTML/PHP Form validation

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a textbox in a form, which I want to validate as follows:

**TextField name = enrollment Id**

Enrollment id has a length of 10 and is in a  pattern like TCA1409032, three characters followed by 7 digits. The characters can be TCA, TEN and many more.

How do I perform this validation in my form?

Comment: Use regex in PHP to test the value, or use a jQuery / Javascript plugin to mask the input, or to validate the fields. Try something by yourself, best way to learn.

Comment: You can use a regex in JS, PHP, or HTML5. Client side checks (js/html) can be bypassed. https://regex101.com/r/SejV6k/1/

Comment: use this (\^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{7}$\).test('Enrollment') if return true the valid if false then not valid

Answer (score 0):

You can either add:

1. clientside validation (probably preferred method for your needs): add javascript handler to validate the form before submitting.  Then handler should use a regex pattern to match the string length and character types.
2. server-side validation:  add php functionality to check the value (also using regex), and on success- handle the submission; otherwise return to the form with error messaging.

For reference, check out:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test
- https://regexr.com/